# Is there any way to increase my crafting success rate?

Tags: sequence

I can't recall if this was mentioned in the tutorial or not and I can't seem to find a way to review the tutorial. Each item has a specific chance of success based on its crafting difficulty. Is this set in stone for each item, or are there ways I can influence this success rate at all, like by leveling up, using an item or scroll that increases the success rate (if they exist), etc.? Or are the success percentages for items completely immutable?

[image: Sequence crafting]

Comment: You can use experience points to increase the success chances. I'm unsure of which buttons you actually use to do this tho. My best guess would be the arrow keys: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UBkvxRBtQEw#t=1162s

Comment: @mordi2k Ah ha! I thought I remembered them mentioning this somewhere. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept. :)

Comment: So, do you use the arrow keys for it?

Comment: @mordi2k Yes, you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can spend experience points to increase the chances of success as show in this video:

You do this by pressing the arrow keys:

- <kbd>→</kbd> Increases the amount of experience used.
- <kbd>←</kbd> Decreases the amount of experience used.